# Java web application with S3 File Manager

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, amazon-s3

I am working on a web application based on Java/JSP and I need to include a web based file explorer that connects to an Amazon S3 bucket that can handle the basic file explorer tasks such as upload, delete, rename and navigation. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried simply creating a wrapper to wrap around s3cmd ? that would be the ultra lazy way to do it. since then all the protocol handling is done for you and all you have to do is feed/parse its input and output

S3cmd is extremely well documented and pretty simple to use.

Comment: I was looking for an existing library the fits, if i was going to do that I would probably be better to just use the AWS SDK for Java.

Comment: the AWS SDK for java will definitely do the job, although I believe that you have to muck around slightly with regions when setting everything up, In addition to this you may have to paginate your requests (whereas s3cmd does all of that for you.)